# JS Code didn't work, trying do a demo in css lessons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visual-studio-code

but there's a demo that uses JS and CSS. I have been  trying to fix it for about 3-4 hours.

(FYI after 2 hours struggling I have found half of solution. I'm using Safari and should but `-webkit-transform`) Now I have tried the css added directly to the element and it worked, but it doesn't worked using JS.

I have download `jquery-1.11.3.js` and import it.

[The lesson that I'm watching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vafp5xr_bxk&index=1&list=WL) (ON 3:45:55)

And when I `click` nothing happened. WHY!?

Login.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='LoginCSS.css' />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="banner">Please Login!</div>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div id="demoButton" class="default">
            Submit!
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#demoButton').mousedown(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('default');
                $(this).addClass('shrink');
            });
            $('#demoButton').mouseup(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('shrink');
                $(this).addClass('default');
            }); 
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

---

LoginCSS.css

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana;   
}    
label {
    float: left;
    width: 75px;
}    
div {
    margin-bottom: .4em;
}    
#banner {
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    font-size : 4em;
    text-align: center;
}    
#demoButton {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 1.25em;
    width: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: .3em;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: crosshair;
}    
#demoButton::selection {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}    
.shrink{
    transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
}    
.default {
    transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
}
```

Comment: what didn't worked? atleast tell us the behaviour you expected.

Comment: I'm expecting that when i click on demoButton div its shrink

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using JQuery you can do it with CSS using `:active`

```
#demoButton:active {
    transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
}
```

Docs:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Comment: Best way to do it but unfortunatly that probably wont get OP their marks in class...

Comment: Oh well... Can't win them all ;)